# How to add parameters to a window event / mouse wheel in svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3

I would like to listen to the mouse wheel, and if the mouse is position above a certain element, cancel the default and do my stuff instead.

For now I just want to log the event and prevent it:

```
  const handleWheel = e => {
    console.log(e);
    e.preventDefault();
  };
```

Using svelte this is what I came up with:

```
<svelte:window on:wheel={handleWheel} />
```

Unfortantly this only lets me log the event, and gives this error message:

> Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener invocation.

Using pure JS the solution is to add a parameter:

```
window.addEventListener("wheel", handleWheel, { passive: false});
```

But I can find no way in the svelte documentation that mentions how this can be done. So how would you do this the svelte way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, your code does work as it is for me...

```html
<script>
  const handleWheel = e => {
    console.log(e);
    e.preventDefault();
  };
</script>

<svelte:window on:wheel={handleWheel} />
```

See [in the REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/da0b098337814eb08419a8bdb770caf8?version=3.18.1).

Maybe it's your browser, but I guess it might also be the REPL itself (if that's what you were using) that may have some issues with `<svelte:window />` events, and displays outdated logs...

Actually, your solution would do the opposite of what you want, and cause the warning:

```js
window.addEventListener("wheel", handleWheel, { passive: true });
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener):

> **passive**
>
> A Boolean which, if true, indicates that the function specified by listener will never call preventDefault(). If a passive listener does call preventDefault(), the user agent will do nothing other than generate a console warning.

With that out of the way, Svelte's way to add options to event listeners is with **modifiers**.

For example:

```html
<svelte:window on:wheel|preventDefault={handleWheel} />

<svelte:window on:wheel|passive={handleWheel} />
```

They're combinable, but `preventDefault` and `passive` don't go well together, so let's use another one:

```html
<svelte:window on:wheel|preventDefault|once={handleWheel} />
```

See Svelte's [docs on events](https://svelte.dev/docs#on_element_event) for available modifiers, and details:

> The following modifiers are available:
>
> preventDefault — calls event.preventDefault() before running the handler
>
> stopPropagation — calls event.stopPropagation(), preventing the event reaching the next element
>
> passive — improves scrolling performance on touch/wheel events (Svelte will add it automatically where it's safe to do so)
>
> capture — fires the handler during the capture phase instead of the bubbling phase
>
> once — remove the handler after the first time it runs
>
> Modifiers can be chained together, e.g. `on:click|once|capture={...}`.

Comment: Seems like the |passive modifier sets passive to true, not false. But I was able to solve this with an onMount function, se example here (works with chrome) https://svelte.dev/repl/8a3717b985474d1cbd2bd6ce28a80c15?version=3.18.1

Comment: Btw, you are correct, my code sample had true where it should have been false. I've fixed that in the question

Comment: Your solution is perfectly valid. Svelte hasn't a vocation of totally isolating you from normal JS, quite the contrary. You should post it as an answer and accept it, if you feel that's what work best for you. That being said, `<svelte:window on:wheel|preventDefault={handleWheel} />` is working as expected (prevent scroll) for me in Chrome / desktop... Isn't it working for you? What's your browser?

Comment: |PreventDefault prevents me from scrolling, but I only want to prevent the scrolling when the mouse is over a given element (a calendar)

Comment: Kind of make more sense. You can add this to any element on the page: `<div on:wheel|preventDefault={handleWheel}>` [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/e2df87735aab44a5ad4da1731cc4814c?version=3.18.1). The result in the REPL is not perfect. Browsers are touchy with scroll events, because it can ruin performance. I would try toggling a flag in `mouseenter` / `mouseleave` and prevent scroll in `wheel` on window, when the flag in on.

Answer (score 3):

Currently, there's no way to do this idiomatically with an event handler, because Chrome [broke the web](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/02/scrolling-intervention) by making certain event listeners passive by default. There's an [open Svelte issue](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/2068) that would address this.

In the meantime, the most idiomatic way would probably be to use an action:

```html
<script>
  let scrollable = true;

  const wheel = (node, options) => {
    let { scrollable } = options;

    const handler = e => {
      if (!scrollable) e.preventDefault();
    };

    node.addEventListener('wheel', handler, { passive: false });

    return {
      update(options) {
        scrollable = options.scrollable;
      },
      destroy() {
        node.removeEventListener('wheel', handler, { passive: false });
      }
    };
  };
</script>

<svelte:window use:wheel={{scrollable}} />
```

[Demo here.](https://svelte.dev/repl/2bdbf66371a3418e9e3eda076df6e32d?version=3.18.1)

Comment: Here's the link to the more recent update that broke mousewheel events https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/02/scrolling-intervention